# In JAVA, after thread notify, what does it execute immediately? wait for the lock or cpu schedule

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, blocked

I just want to know, after Object.notify(), the thread is compete with all the other RUNNABLE thread for the CPU schedule or only compete with the thread which in the same object monitor for the lock?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and adhere to the tips given there in order to avoid down votes or your question being closed. That being said, did you read up on this in the documentation already? Is there anything that's missing or that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

The chosen thread is woken immediately (as much as allowed by the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)). However, it wont be able to reacquire the lock, because the thread calling `notify` has it. Also the thread may not be scheduled, particularly on single-threaded hardware.

If you're trying to rely on these sorts of details, you're probably doing it wrong. That's not a particularly helpful comment, but I don't think there is anything that can be written that will suddenly let you grok concurrency.

Comment: @DXTZ, Note! "woken immediately" does not mean that the thread will immediately resume execution. It means that the thread is immediately marked as _elgible_ to resume execution. Most implementations of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) will "wake" a thread by asking the operating system to mark it as elgible to resume. The JRE allows the operating system to decide when the thread actually _will_ resume.

Comment: @SolomonSlow As I say, it wont be able to reacquire the lock. Though I guess an implementation may be able to combine the `notify` with the end of the `synchronized` block. There's long been a tradition of not necessarily being a direct correlation to OS threads. Notably JRockit. Project Loom take it further although no longer "fibres" (because of re-entrant locks, but blamed on `ThreadLocal` usage). Anyway, exact behaviour is implementation defined, and trying to second guess precise details is no way to think about it.